# ASP.NET CORE, How read all files in a folder that is used from another process

Tags: c#, asp.net, file

im trying to read a folder from a remote machine, inside this folder there are many txt files.
The machine is writing every time new datas inside the folder.

```
string str = "";
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\192.168.1.209\user\HST\");
            FileInfo[] Files = d.GetFiles("*.txt");

            foreach (FileInfo file in Files)
            {
                str = str + ", " + file.Name;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception pp)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(GlobalVariables.errorFolderLocation + "erroreLettura.1.209.txt", pp.ToString());
        }
```

This is my code, I don't understand how to get these datas, because i get this error: "the system call level is not correct".
For example, if i try to delete the folder or a file, i get error because it's already used by another process.
So, is there a solution to "bypass" this error?

EDIT 1:
I need read every row of every file, i get the error on DirectoryInfo.
If i acces on the folders and files it works fine.
I need read this folder/files in 3 different machine, but only in this (192.168.1.209) not working, and its the only machine where i get error when i try to delete a file

Comment: What do you want to do with the files? What line raises the error? Is the share to another Windows computer & is authentication configured for whatever service account your ASP runs under? Does it work if accessed manually?

Comment: I've update my question

Comment: Try `Directory.EnumerateFiles()` to loop the files instead?

Comment: Nothing, it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you are not able to delete a file which is in use by another process or delete a folder that contains a file in use, or whatever other operation that has not been specified to be accessed on the other process. In order to achieve this, the process which has the file in use, must open it with a share access, `FileShare` from `System.IO` .NET library.